# Transformar elementos de uma string em array PHP

Tags: php, array, preg-match

O mysql retorna a seguinte string:
["Elemento1", "Elemento2", "Elemento3", "Elemento4", "Elemento5", "Elemento6"]

Preciso transformar cada uma das palavras entre "" em um elemento de um array. Tentei a partir das funções preg_split e preg_match_all mas não consegui chegar a expressão regular correta.

Comment: Se é um JSON, por que não tenta `json_decode`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss porque a JSON_EXTRACT é uma função executada na query do mysql que trás somente a informações desejadas do JSON sem precisar percorrer ele no PHP

Comment: Mas ele converte a sua *string* no *array* que precisa, se é que entendi certo o que quer fazer.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss ele transforma o resultado em uma string. Preciso transformar o que esta entre " " em componentes de um array.

Comment: Veja minha resposta. Parece que você não entendeu bem como a `json_decode` funciona; mas se não for o que respondi, peço que edite a pergunta e esclareça melhor o que precisa fazer, pois da forma que está dá a entender que basta utilizar essa função, pois ela gera o *array* com todas as *strings*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o retorno da sua SQL é a *string*:

```
$str = '["Elemento1", "Elemento2", "Elemento3", "Elemento4", "Elemento5", "Elemento6"]';
```

Então basta usar a função [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) para gerar o *array*:

```
$arr = json_decode($str);
```

O *array* gerado será:

```
array (
  0 => 'Elemento1',
  1 => 'Elemento2',
  2 => 'Elemento3',
  3 => 'Elemento4',
  4 => 'Elemento5',
  5 => 'Elemento6',
)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/kAItzB)</sup>

Comment: Funcionou! Eu não sabia que a função json_decode também convertia strings

Comment: Segue o manual: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php

Comment: @RomuloSousa a documentação já está linkada na resposta xD

Comment: Foi mal haha, não percebi.